# How can I create method to generate new LinkedList?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, identifier

I am trying to create a method that creates new `LinkedLists`. I want to pass a `String` parameter to use as the new `LinkedList` identifier but I'm getting an error "`java: variable s is already defined in method createQueue(java.lang.String)`"

Is there anyway to use a `String` to create the new `LinkedList` like this?
I need to do it this way for an assignment so I can't change the method declaration.

```
public void createQueue(String s){

   LinkedList<obj> s = new LinkedList<obj>();

}
```

I may be looking at this the wrong way also. I'm just trying to create the linkedList atm. But my requirements are as follows:

boolean addQueue(String)

This method will have a String parameter. It will return a boolean.
It will add a new queue specified by the parameter. E.g. addQueue(“ready”) would create a new queue called “ready” to the list of queues. If there is already a queue by the specified name, then this method will return false. E.g. If you already have a queue named “ready” and you call addQueue(“ready”), it will return false. Otherwise, it will create the queue and return true.

Comment: "It will add a new queue specified by the parameter". Add it where?

Comment: There isn't specifications for this but I am creating a list that will hold the Queues. It just need to be able to hold any number of Queues from 1-n.

Comment: So you're writing a class that needs to hold a list of queues, and this method should add a queue to the list?

Comment: Yes exactly. The queues will also hold objects from another custom class so there is a method to AddPcb(Pcb p, String s) that will add the Pcb object to the queue with matching name.

Comment: And what exactly should be the procedure for converting a String into a LinkedList? What does the String contain?

Comment: Well that is where I'm getting stuck. The string should just be used to name the queue. If I call addQueue("Ready") it needs to create a new LinkedList with the name "Ready".

Comment: I'm assuming the string would only contain a single word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain a collection of queues. Because each queue has a unique name, the most appropriate collection is `Map`:

```
public class QueueManager {

    private Map<String, List<Pcb>> queues = new HashMap<String, List<Pcb>>();

    public boolean addQueue(String queueName) {
        if (queues.containsKey(queueName)) {
            // There is already a queue with that name
            return false;
        } else {
            queues.put(queueName, new ArrayList<Pcb>());
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I made the assumption that the queue is implemented with an `ArrayList`, but of course `LinkedList`would work similarly. Then the method `addPcb()`is quite obvious:

```
public void addPcb(Pcb pcb, String queueName) {
    List<Pcb> queue = queues.get(queueName);
    if (queue != null) {
        queue.add(pcb);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Queue does not exist: " + queueName);
    }
}
```

An alternative implementation of `addPcb()`, using `addQueue()`could be:

```
public void addPcb(Pcb pcb, String queueName) {
    addQueue(queueName);
    List<Pcb> queue = queues.get(queueName);
    queue.add(pcb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two different variables named `s` - the `String s` parameter (which is a variable) and `LinkedList<obj> s`.

Just rename either one of them.

Comment: But I need to use the String 's' to name the new LinkedList, how can I do this?

Comment: @ChrisMoore You can't. You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope. Why not rename `String s` to `String someOtherNameWhichIsNotS`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe I'm thinking about what's being asked wrong. Would you  mind to take a look at my requirement?

boolean addQueue(String)
This method will have a String parameter. It will return a boolean.
It will add a new queue specified by the parameter. E.g. addQueue(“ready”) would create a new queue called “ready” to the list of queues. If there is already a queue by the specified name, then this method will return false. E.g. If you already have a queue named “ready” and you call addQueue(“ready”), it will return false. Else it will create the queue and return true.

Comment: Sure. Edit the question to specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've added info to the question